# Ведение логов в ASP .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, логирование

Подскажите готовый проект в котором логи пишутся в базу данных ( не важно какую но желательно легкую и бесплатную) 
Я написал свою [реализацию](https://github.com/milovidov983/WebLiteDbLog/tree/master) с LiteDB но так как я начинающий программист, то не уверен что все сделал правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) или [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)(это значительно облегчит Вам жизнь)

[Здесь](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreNlog) я думаю Вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос.

Вот пример реализации конфига для БД:

```
<!-- write log message to database -->
    <target xsi:type="Database" name="db">
      <!-- SQL command to be executed for each entry -->
      <commandText>INSERT INTO [LogEntries](TimeStamp, Message, Level, Logger) VALUES(getutcdate(), @msg, @level, @logger)</commandText>

      <!-- parameters for the command -->
      <parameter name="@msg" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />

      <!-- connection string -->
      <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
      <connectionString>server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=MyLogs;integrated security=sspi</connectionString>

      <!-- commands to install database -->
      <install-command>
        <text>CREATE DATABASE MyLogs</text>
        <connectionString>server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;integrated security=sspi</connectionString>
        <ignoreFailures>true</ignoreFailures>
      </install-command>

      <install-command>
        <text>
          CREATE TABLE LogEntries(
          id int primary key not null identity(1,1),
          TimeStamp datetime2,
          Message nvarchar(max),
          level nvarchar(10),
          logger nvarchar(128))
        </text>
      </install-command>

      <!-- commands to uninstall database -->
      <uninstall-command>
        <text>DROP DATABASE MyLogs</text>
        <connectionString>server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=master;integrated security=sspi</connectionString>
        <ignoreFailures>true</ignoreFailures>
      </uninstall-command>
    </target>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам. Читал что лучше вести лог в NoSQL базе данных, это верно?

Comment: мое личное мнение, при большом обьеме данных лучше в БД, если данных(логов) не так много и нет задачи хранить их долго то да лучше в NoSQL. Хотя для себя я выбрал золотую середину "SQLite", и БД и ресурсо-затрат очень мало.